# How to save a text with tabs and new lines in Firestore and get it back intact?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Realtime database used to add \n, \t, etc but it doesn't seem to be the case for Firestore. this might be something basic I'm missing. Either way, how can I save something like this and get it back with new lines and tabs intact:

```
value: "test 
        newline 
        another line"
```

currently, I get it back like this:

```
value: "test newline another line"
```

Answer (score 5):

From my simple tests, Firestore does preserve new lines and tabs. How are you displaying the value? If it's HTML, wrapping the value in a `<p>` tag will crush the spacing. If you use a `<pre>` tag, you should see the spacing.

Answer (score 0):

Pre is not working with firestore seems there is not possible ways for now to save preformatted text in firestore

Comment: @JRLtechwriting i have used pre, pre-wrap and all that same issue you have to explicitly write a function that will manipulate the DOM after compilation using ngAfterview directive in case of angular and i am still working on that.
    .subscribe(projects => {
        this.projects = projects;
        this.projects.forEach(element => {
            Object.keys(element)
                .filter(item => typeof(item) == 'string' && element.item) //only using replace on strings
                .forEach(item => element.item = element.item.replace("\n", "<br/>"));
        });